# Jquery .focus()-loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to apply a new Style to my Submit-Button if its focused.So if its focused, the Style changes, but i cant get rid of it.Means that i cant lose focus on my Button.The other Problem is, that when focused the button moves like 2-3pixel down.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".login").hover(function() {
                $(this).toggleClass("hoverbutton");
            });
            $(".login").focus(function(){
                $(this).toggleClass("focusbutton");
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Hope someone can help me out with this :)

Comment: you need to listen to `.blur()` as well to remove the class

Comment: First: why are you doing this with jQuery when you have CSS `:hover` and `:focus`. Second your added classes probably have different margin/paddings/border applied and that is why it moves. If you want proper help you need to post HTML and CSS. A fiddle would be even nicer.

Comment: there is no specific reason, i did it before in CSS, but i thought it would be good to use some jquery since i am a beginner to jquery

Comment: @Mikey http://jsfiddle.net/j3mpbtw5/

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".login").hover(function () {
                $(this).toggleClass("hoverbutton");
            }, function () {
                $(this).toggleClass("Normalbutton");
            });
        });
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".login").hover(function () {
        $(this)
            .removeClass("normalbtn")
            .addClass("hover_btn");
    }, function() {
        $(this)
            .removeClass("hover_btn")
            .addClass("normalbtn");
   });
});
```

[Refer Here](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Answer (score 1):

According to the jQuery API (http://api.jquery.com/hover/), hover accepts two functions:

```
$( ".login" ).hover(
    function() {
        // This part is called on Mouse over
        $( this ).addClass( "hoverbutton" );
    }, function() {
        // This part is called on Mouse out
        $( this ).removeClass( "hoverbutton" );
    }
);
```

Comment: Even though @Piyush answered first, you provide documentation for it. +1 for the link

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for wrong events,

Look at jQuery API: http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".login").blur(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("focusbutton");
            return false;
        });
```

Added this after .focus() and works fine for me